# TFS2013 Split Team Project from Collection and move to new Collection

Tags: collections

We have an on-premise TFS2013 update 2 with Sharepoint 2013 and need to split a team project out of one collection and create a new collection and put this team project into it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible, there [is a standard procedure to make it so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936158(v=vs.120).aspx). The basic steps (explained in the linked article) are as follows:

- Prepare to split the collection:

  - Detach the collection
  - Back up the collection database
- Split the collection:

  - Restore the collection database with a different Name
  - Attach the original collection database
  - Attach the renamed collection database
  - Delete projects from the split collections
  - Start the collections
- Configure the split collections:

  - Configure Users and Groups for the Split Team Project Collections
  - Configure users and groups for projects in the collections

In the Q&A section be sure to read the extra steps for Reporting and Sharepoint.